# What data type to use for rowkey when mapping Hive to Hbase

Tags: hive, hbase

I am trying to create a Hive table on an existing Hbase table as following:

```
create external table h2h (
    key int -- int or string?
    col1 string
)
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
with serdeproperties ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,info:col1');
```

The [official doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-SimpleCompositeRowKeys) demonstrates several data type for `key`.

How to determine the data type of the column `key` which is mapped to the `rowkey` in the Hbase table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully answer this question, it should be pointed out that HBase keys are stored as byte arrays. That is done for flexibility as clients can then store any kind of data. So, HBase does not really have a concept of type.
This approach is very flexible, but puts on the user the burden of knowing how to serialize/deserialize the data, that is, you should look at some data samples or look at the code that creates/updates the table and see what is used as key.

Try on hbase something like the following

```
 scan 'h2h', {COLUMNS => ['info'], LIMIT => 3 }
```

to see if the key you get is an int or a string.